# Resource Token Provider as an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I've been following the guide in this repo to setup a resource token provider as an Azure function.

https://github.com/adamhockemeyer/Azure-Functions---CosmosDB-ResourceToken-Broker

I've setup the Cosmos DB, App registration, and Azure function with permissions according to the instructions. When I get to step 3 in the guide where I enter `https://{function-url}/.auth/login/{provider}` into my browser I get the following error.

> ADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application: [App id]

## Update

I changed the Reply URL in my App Registration to `https://{function-url}/.auth/login/{provider}/callback` with {function-url} as my Function App URL. Originally I had it set to one of my Function URL's. Now i'm getting a 404 not found error.

[App Registration Redirect URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0by7.png)

[Function App URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiFW3.png)

[Function App Authentication Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzMZp.png)

Comment: seems that you've setup the wrong reply url in your azure ad app registration.

Comment: What should I match the reply url in app registration to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the URL as below in your app registration, then it should work.

**Note**: After adding the URl, go back to the `Authentication / Authorization` in your functionapp, turn off the `Authentication Providers` whcih you configured -> turn off `Authentication / Authorization`, then turn on and configure again, otherwise it seems not become effective.

```
https://{function-url}/.auth/login/{provider}/callback
```

[image]

**Update**:

Turn off all the configuration and create the new AD App like below.

[image]

Comment: Is {function-url} the Function App resource URL or the individual function URL? The first gives me the original error. The second gives me a 404 not found error. Save for both AAD and Google as the provider.

Also, do i need to add a reply URL for each provider I want to support? Like AAD and Google.

Comment: @CodySlade The first one, see my screenshot, did you follow the `Note` in my reply and configure it again?

Comment: Ah, the picture hadn't loaded yet when I was looking at your reply. My URL in my App Registration looks like yours but with my function url. I'm now getting a 404 not found error.

Comment: yes I turned App Service Authentication off, saved and then turned it back on. Still 404 Error. I will upload pictures of my settings.

Comment: @CodySlade Your setting looks correct, it is weird. Try to create a new AD App , see my update. When it has been created, the redirect url will be added automatically, no need to add it manually.

Comment: It's working now after I recreated my app. Thank you!!

Comment: My next step is to access my function app from my Xamarin app, but i've been stuck on this problem for a while https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584931/using-app-center-auth-and-azure-b2c-to-authenticate-with-azure-functions. Would really appreciate some help :).